# pointing to a character in a string using an integer

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  char s[]="man";
  int i=0;
  printf("%c%c\n",s[i],i[s]);
}
```

o/p: m m

*Both s[i] and i[s] prints 'm' and 'm'.
*However s[i]=m, that is acceptable,but how i[s]=m ??
*Can any one explain me about this please.

Comment: Hoosh.....not again...please do a search before posting, at least.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a

Comment: As there are no distinguishing keywords, the dupe is hard to find with a search.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `s[i]` is equivalent to `*(s + i)`, and due to the commutative properties of addition, `*(s + i)` is equal to `*(i + s)` which leads to `i[s]` being valid.